# Display Column names against its corresponding values after using union all in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a requirment where i am using union to merge multiple columns to a single column. But i also want to display corresponding column names of merged column values in new column as shown in Required table image.

I have tried the below query to merge column names

```
select 2am 
  from hourchart 
 union all 
select 4am 
  from hourchart 
 union all 
select 6am 
  from hourchart;
```

Please help!
Thanks in advance

[image: Present table structure after running union]

[image: Required table]

Please help!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Add a dummy field to each select

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor (read atrocious) design. A database table is not a spreadsheet.

Comment: Bit of a harsh comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the value to the `select`s:

```
select '2am' as columnname, `2am` as value from hourchart 
union all 
select '4am', `4am` from hourchart 
union all 
select '6am', `6am` from hourchart;
```